# Is "give" a rude verb?

Tags: verbs

Is "give" a rude verb?
Should I use only "let" with unfamiliar people?

For instance
Let me your phone!
Give me you phone!

Comment: Both of those are rude because they are demanding something. Phrase it such that the listener is presented with an option if you wish to not appear rude: "May I have your phone?"

Comment: _Let_ doesn't mean the same as _give_ . Do you mean _lend_ or _let me have_? In any case, you would only use a command like that with someone you were on very informal terms with.